# Click event for static text

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have a static text named IDC_STATIC for which I made a click event, but it is not getting called when it's clicked.

```
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_STATIC, ontest)  //(begin message map)
void test::ontest(my method)
{
  MessageBox("success");
}
afx_msg void test();  //(header file)
```

What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 8):

The solution is to go to the static text control's properties and enable Notify.